# RecyclerView disabled items changing on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Any help on how to get my `recyclerView` to stop changing the `disabled` items on scroll. here is some example code:

```
@Override
public PlayerSelectRVAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout....., parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerSelectRVAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final Object player = objects.get(position);

    viewHolder.setPlayer(player);
    SetUi(viewHolder);
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final View mView;
    private Object player;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mView = itemView;

        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(mView, getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });
        }
     }
}
```

Ok, so in my `setPlayer` method i am also taking the `itemView` for that holder and setting if its `disabled` or not. then i call my `SetUi` to actually do the view set up.

Thing is it all loads correct until i start scrolling and it messes up. In fact eventually everything becomes `disabled`.

Comment: set disabled player's to show disabled UI, and if a player is enabled update it's UI as well. If you disable one view (that is then recycled), you have to update that view for views being recycled back in. Basically perform the inverse of the UI updates you do to the disabled views for disabled players to players that are enabled. Does that make sense? The logic goes in the onBindViewHolder

Comment: king of the hill. effectively your point on resetting view for the players who are enabled worked. I didn't have to move anything just literally added an else statement that re-enabled that view if it had a player who is to be selectable.

Comment: I figured it was as simple as that, glad it worked :)